# How read mail from /var/spool/postfix/deferred?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

Is there a way to read deffered mail from /var/spool/postfix/deferred. I tried to copy file to my mail directory and see it from webmail but it dosnt work. When im using less or cat it seems like files in spool/deferred are some binary files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to get the message id first with `postqueue -p` then once you have the message id you read it with `postcat -q messageid`. Of course replace *messageid* with the actual id you find.